# How can I optimise this webscraping code for iterative loop?

Tags: pandas, for-loop, optimization, beautifulsoup

This code scrapes [www.oddsportal.com](http://www.oddsportal.com) for all the URLs provided in the code and appends it to a dataframe.

I am not very well versed with iterative logic hence I am finding it difficult to improvise on it.

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs


browser = webdriver.Chrome()


class GameData:

    def __init__(self):
        self.date = []
        self.time = []
        self.game = []
        self.score = []
        self.home_odds = []
        self.draw_odds = []
        self.away_odds = []
        self.country = []
        self.league = []


def parse_data(url):
    browser.get(url)
    df = pd.read_html(browser.page_source, header=0)[0]
    html = browser.page_source
    soup = bs(html, "lxml")
    cont = soup.find('div', {'id': 'wrap'})
    content = cont.find('div', {'id': 'col-content'})
    content = content.find('table', {'class': 'table-main'}, {'id': 'tournamentTable'})
    main = content.find('th', {'class': 'first2 tl'})
    if main is None:
        return None
    count = main.findAll('a')
    country = count[1].text
    league = count[2].text
    game_data = GameData()
    game_date = None
    for row in df.itertuples():
        if not isinstance(row[1], str):
            continue
        elif ':' not in row[1]:
            game_date = row[1].split('-')[0]
            continue
        game_data.date.append(game_date)
        game_data.time.append(row[1])
        game_data.game.append(row[2])
        game_data.score.append(row[3])
        game_data.home_odds.append(row[4])
        game_data.draw_odds.append(row[5])
        game_data.away_odds.append(row[6])
        game_data.country.append(country)
        game_data.league.append(league)
    return game_data


urls = {
"https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/england/premier-league/results/#/page/1",
"https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/england/premier-league/results/#/page/2",
"https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/england/premier-league/results/#/page/3",
"https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/england/premier-league/results/#/page/4",
"https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/england/premier-league/results/#/page/5",
"https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/england/premier-league/results/#/page/6",
"https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/england/premier-league/results/#/page/7",
"https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/england/premier-league/results/#/page/8",
"https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/england/premier-league/results/#/page/9",
"https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/england/premier-league-2019-2020/results/#/page/1",
"https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/england/premier-league-2019-2020/results/#/page/2",
"https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/england/premier-league-2019-2020/results/#/page/3",
"https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/england/premier-league-2019-2020/results/#/page/4",
"https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/england/premier-league-2019-2020/results/#/page/5",
"https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/england/premier-league-2019-2020/results/#/page/6",
"https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/england/premier-league-2019-2020/results/#/page/7",
"https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/england/premier-league-2019-2020/results/#/page/8",
"https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/england/premier-league-2019-2020/results/#/page/9",
"https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/england/premier-league-2018-2019/results/#/page/1",
"https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/england/premier-league-2018-2019/results/#/page/2",
"https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/england/premier-league-2018-2019/results/#/page/3",
"https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/england/premier-league-2018-2019/results/#/page/4",
"https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/england/premier-league-2018-2019/results/#/page/5",
"https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/england/premier-league-2018-2019/results/#/page/6",
"https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/england/premier-league-2018-2019/results/#/page/7",
"https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/england/premier-league-2018-2019/results/#/page/8",
"https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/england/premier-league-2018-2019/results/#/page/9",
}

if __name__ == '__main__':

    results = None

    for url in urls:
        game_data = parse_data(url)
        if game_data is None:
            continue
        result = pd.DataFrame(game_data.__dict__)
        if results is None:
            results = result
        else:
            results = results.append(result, ignore_index=True)

print(results)

|     | date        | time   | game                             | score   |   home_odds |   draw_odds |   away_odds | country   | league                   |
|-----|-------------|--------|----------------------------------|---------|-------------|-------------|-------------|-----------|--------------------------|
|   0 | 12 May 2019 | 14:00  | Brighton - Manchester City       | 1:4     |       14.95 |        7.75 |        1.2  | England   | Premier League 2018/2019 |
|   1 | 12 May 2019 | 14:00  | Burnley - Arsenal                | 1:3     |        2.54 |        3.65 |        2.75 | England   | Premier League 2018/2019 |
|   2 | 12 May 2019 | 14:00  | Crystal Palace - Bournemouth     | 5:3     |        1.77 |        4.32 |        4.22 | England   | Premier League 2018/2019 |
|   3 | 12 May 2019 | 14:00  | Fulham - Newcastle               | 0:4     |        2.45 |        3.55 |        2.92 | England   | Premier League 2018/2019 |
|   4 | 12 May 2019 | 14:00  | Leicester - Chelsea              | 0:0     |        2.41 |        3.65 |        2.91 | England   | Premier League 2018/2019 |
|   5 | 12 May 2019 | 14:00  | Liverpool - Wolves               | 2:0     |        1.31 |        5.84 |       10.08 | England   | Premier League 2018/2019 |
|   6 | 12 May 2019 | 14:00  | Manchester Utd - Cardiff         | 0:2     |        1.3  |        6.09 |        9.78 | England   | Premier League 2018/2019 |
```

As you can see the URLs can be optimised to run through all pages in that league/branch

[inspect element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qW3LL.png)

If I can accomodate this code to run iteratively for every page as in this inspect element below:

[Inspect Element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CODmT.jpg)

That can be really useful and helpful.

How can I optimise this code to iteratively run for every page?

Comment: I don't understand the question

Comment: @QHarr The code above scrapes for multiple URLs. I am trying to get it to the stage where one URL will link to the page and the multiple page lists within that webpage will be scraped with the above code https://i.stack.imgur.com/qW3LL.png